# MsBuild can't find lib

Tags: c++, msbuild

I am using the following script to build a C++ project:

```
msbuild D:\proj.vcxproj /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false /p:AssemblySearchPaths="D:\Import\GenericAIC\Include" /p:AdditionalLibPaths="D:\Export\Release"
```

I am getting an error that it can't find a certain lib. that lib is present in the `D:\Export\Release folder` which is set as `p:AdditionalLibPaths`

The project compiles perfectly in Visual studio.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are building a project and not a solution,
you don't have the  **$SolutionDir**, and MSBuild cant interpert all the macros in the project file.

 you just need to add /Property:SolutionDir="" and everything will compile.